# Why Binding DataTable doesn't work in XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, datatable, objectdataprovider

My MainWindow Class have a property called "DataTable":

```
'Table To import the Excel Sheet
Public Property DataTable As DataTable
```

An Excel Sheet sets the DataTable property. My question is why I cannot bind that property to a DataGrid. The following code doesn't work:

```
<DataGrid Name="TestGrid" Visibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataTable}">
</DataGrid>
```

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859192/wpf-datagrid-binding-to-datatable-in-xaml) seems to be unclear and doesn't explain too much about how to use the ObjectDataProvider Class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind DataTable to Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770438/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagrid)

Comment: @KeithStein I read that question too. There is no accepted answer and the approach is from code-behind. I want to make it from XAML. Maybe it can't be done with XAML only?

Comment: What if instead of `{Binding DataTable}`, you tried `{Binding DataTable.DefaultView}`?

Comment: @KeithStein I tried that too before to post this question. Didn't work.

Comment: Wow, this is actually an interesting thing. I did some testing. In all cases `ItemsSource` gets set to the same, correct value. The only difference is *when* the value gets set. If you take your code as you have it, and then manually change `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and then back to `true`, the correct columns come up. This seems like a bug in `DataGrid`.